# Дочерняя тема в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Проблема с созданием дочерней темы Divi. Сделал все по [инструкции](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html). В целом стили корректно работают но в некоторых местах инпуты поменяли вид или не работают. Такое впечатление что какие то файлы не подгружаются с родительской темы.

Файл style.css:

```html
/*
Theme Name: Divi-child
Template: Divi
*/

/* import parent css */
@import url("../Divi/style.css");
```

Апдейт - стили некоректные только по отношению к инпутам, вот допустим в родительской теме Divi есть style с такими свойствами:

```css
.post-56 .et_pb_section:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: rgba(244,244,244,1);
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 42px;
    padding-left: 250px;
    padding-right: 250px;
}
```

а в дочерней его нету, кто подскажет что это за инлайт свойства генерируются и как добавить в родительскую тему?

Comment: Актуальная правильная инструкция: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: Пока не понимаю, почему у вас какие-то проблемы. Удаленный ответ содержит такой же код, как и в инструкции Divi https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/divi-child-theme OK, ваш код @import мог бы работать неправильно, если были бы сложные зависимости. Но там такого нет.

Comment: Показанные вами инлайн-стили генерируются в зависимости от настроек блоков внутри страницы, в админке страницы. Как они могут не срабатывать в дочерней теме - непонятно.

Comment: Почему вы не подключаете стили родительской темы через functions.php